# ThreadLocal race condition with

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate

I have a little problem with race condition.

```
public class MyClass1 {
    static ThreadLocal<MyInterface> threads = new ThreadLocal();

    static MyInterface getThread(){
       return threads.get();
    }    

    static String saveId(String name){
       return getThread.saveId());
    }    
}

public interface MyInterface {
     String saveId(String name);
}

public class MyClass2 implements MyInterface {

    MyDao dao;

    public String saveId(String name){

    Session s= dao.getCurrentSession();
    String id =  (String)s.save(new MyObject(name));
    return id;

   }

}
```

And my problem, how is better choice to exclude race condition while I try to save the Object into DB while I use singleton and hibernate?

I think, that correct solution is

```
private volatile String id;

public synchronized String saveId(String name){

        Session s= dao.getCurrentSession();
        id =  (String)s.save(new MyObject(name));
        return id;   
   }
```

Am I wrong?

P.S. 
My second guess about code:

```
    public String saveId(String name){

    Session s= dao.getCurrentSession();
    String id = s.createQuery("select id from MyObject where name= :name order by id desc").setParameter("name", name).uniqueResult();

    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
     id = makeId(name);
    }

    return id; 
   }

 public String makeId(String name) {

   String id = s.createQuery("select id from MyObject where name= :name order by id desc").setParameter("name", name).uniqueResult();

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(id)) {

            synchronized (MyClass2.class){
            id =  (String)s.save(new MyObject(name));
            s.flush();
            }
        } 
     return id;
}
```

Comment: Why would you need the thread local? Your code is thread safe so why would you need multiple instances? Your second code isn't threadsafe (you are keeping state in a singleton).

Comment: ThreadLocal is legacy code, so I have to use that and multithreading is used of company needs. About second code, why does it still singleton? I think that volatile used between every threads, doesn`t it?

Comment: If multiple threads excute the same code they will share the id. Keep it inside the method and there is no issue. Basically your code was fine as is. The `ThreadLocal` doesn't really add anything but complexity, you could replace that with a single instance of `MyClass2` without noticing any performance impact (or threading issue).

Comment: So, If 2 or more threads in 1 moment will try to save 1 object with equal unique 'name' there is no problem with that? I would not get any exception ((thread trying insert new object) - 1) times, would I?

Comment: If there is a constraint in your DB 1 of the threads will get an exception, that  the name is already present. If there is nothing preventing the insertion it will be inserted.

Comment: Ok, so now we find the root of problem, that I will get multiple equals insertions which doesn`t need. How to avoid that?

Comment: You aren't avoiding that in  your threadlocal one either. The behavior doesn't change and is a totally different question then what you asked here. The only way to reliably prevent duplicate inserts is by a constraint on the DB side.

Comment: @M.Deinum I change my question. Is it solution correct?

Comment: No. The only reliable way to do this is by a constraint in the database. If you have multiple instances running, syncronizing won't help. There is nothing preventing you from inserting after the select so even do a chech before the insert won't be a 100% solution.

Comment: Bad answer, but, anyway, thank you

Comment: Why is this a bad answer? It won't help in a 100% reliable way and definitly not if you have multiple instances of this code running (then the syncronize simply won't help). I'm sorry if that isn't the answer you wanted to hear, but that is how it is. As mentioned the only reliable way is a constraint in the db. You could catch it in your code and then do a select for the ID.

Comment: Bad answer, because I can't change this situation only via java, as I understand, I have to change DB for this 'MyObject'. It is not easy way :)

Comment: You can do that without changing java code. `ALTER TABLE MyObject ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_NAME UNIQUE (name);` and you are done. Unless you want to always return the ID you also need 2 additional lines in java. That and only that is the 100% reliable way of doing this. Or don't use JPA but plain SQL and use an INSERT with MERGE or UPSERT (which will do an update instead of insert on error) and return the generated/updated PK. Both will work, the first certainlly, the second depends if your database supports this.

Comment: It is possible that I absolutely confused, but let's imagine: 1st thread make select from DB any 'Id' by 'Name'. There is no 'id' and it tries to insert, supposably
, with pure SQL, and It gets exception, becaus of 2nd thread have already checked that there is no that 'name' in db and inserted new 'MyObject'. So, I should only again do 'SELECT' by name in the 'catch' area?

Comment: When doing a constraint, yu don't need the initial select, as that select gives no guarantees that it doesn't exist after the select. Just do the insert, catch the exception, then do a select. Or do an UPSERT in SQL instead (if supported by your DB but then you cannot use JPA).

Comment: Thank you. May you make an answer to accept that? In any form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `ThreadLocal` or `syncronized` won't help to create a 100% solid solution. There are only 3 reliable ways of doing this

1. Having a unique constraint on the database and read ID on error
2. Doing an UPSERT instead of INSERT (basically does an UPDATE when INSERT fails) and return the id. Requires an additional SELECT for the ID.
3. Doing an INSERT with a WHERE clause to prevent the INSERT of name already exists. Requires an additional SELECT for the ID.

The second and third are only feasible witha plain SQL query. The second depends on the support on your database. The first option should always work.

## Unique Constraint on DB

1. Alter your table `ALTER TABLE MyObject ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_MYOBJECT_NAME UNIQUE(name);`
2. Then your method should do a `save` and on error read line from db.

   ```
   public String saveId(String name){
     Session s= dao.getCurrentSession();
     try {
       return (String) s.save(new MyObject(name));
     } catch (PersistenceException pe) {
       return s.createQuery("SELECT x FROM MyObject X where x.name=:name").setParameter("name", name).getSingleResult().getId(); 
     }
   }
   ```
3. You don't need the `ThreadLocal` stuff as there is nothing shared between threads in your `saveId` method and you can safely reuse a single instance between threads (each will have their own `Session` etc.